# Error 401 Unauthorized in Browser and Postman ok

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, passport.js

Good morning people

I am setting up the front-end for testing, In my application I use Passport, Token Jwt for authentication. At Postman, everything is ok! I can authenticate myself.
Now in the Browser, I log in it generates the token, however when trying to execute a route protected by the passport it returns me unauthorized
Follow my code. I'm a beginner, first post on the stackoverflow.

**Routes.js**

```
app.route('/rifas') 
   .all(app.config.passport.authenticate())
   .post(app.api.rifas.saverifa)
```

**Passport.js**

```
const authSecret = process.env.authSecret
const passport = require('passport')
const passportJwt =  require('passport-jwt')    
const { Strategy, ExtractJwt } = passportJwt 

module.exports = app => {


    const options = {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: authSecret
    }
    const strategy = new Strategy(options,(payload, done) => {
        app.db('users')
        .where({id: payload.id})
        .first()
        .then( user => {
            if(user) {
                done(null, {id: user.id, email: user.email})
            }
            else {
                done(null,false)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => done(err,false))

    })
    passport.use(strategy)
    return {
        initialize: () => passport.initialize(),
        authenticate: () => passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false})
    }

}
```

**Archive api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'localhost:3333',
})
export default api
```

**Archive of front-end**

```
 async function handleLogin (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
     const {data: token} = await axios.post('http://localhost:3333/signin', {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
      window.location.href="http://localhost:3000/Header"
      alert(`Logado com sucesso ${name}`)
    }catch(e) {
      alert('Erro no login')
    }
  }
```

Comment: I believe that when navigating using window.location you are actually losing you execution session and axios does not hold the token you got. you might want to try to store the token in sessionStorage or localStorage and apply if in the next requests from there